# Promise<void | IEmployee> is not assignable to type Promise<IEmployee>?

Tags: angular2-services

```
getEmployeesByCode(empCode: string): Promise<IEmployee> {
            return this._http.get("http://localhost:24535/api/employees/" + empCode)
                .map((response: Response) => <IEmployee>response.json())
                .toPromise()
                .catch(this.handlePromiseError);
        }



     handlePromiseError(error: Response) {
            debugger;
            console.error(error);
            throw (error);
        }
```

> Error  TS2322  Type 'Promise' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.
>     Type 'void | IEmployee' is not assignable to type 'IEmployee'.
>       Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'IEmployee'.

Answer (score 0):

```
getEmployeesByCode(empCode: string): Promise<IEmployee> {
            return this._http.get("http://localhost:24535/api/employees/" + empCode)
                .map((response: Response) => <IEmployee>response.json())
                .toPromise()
                .catch(this.handlePromiseError);
        }
```

Change Promise to Promise in the above method and in employee.component.ts file change the calling function like below: just cast the response to IEmoyee

```
this._empSerivce.getEmployee(this.code).then(
            (empData) => {
                if (empData == null) {
                    this.statusMessage = "Employee with the specified code does not exists.";
                }
                else {
                    //console.log(empData);
                    this.employee = <IEmployee>empData;


                }
            }
        ).catch(
            (error) => this.statusMessage = "Problem while loading service. Please try again later.")
```